# Is this GLSL mat4 vertex attribute being set up correctly?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-array-object

I am using this vertex information as input to a GL_POINTS geometry shader.

```
struct Vertex
{
    glm::mat4 transform;
    glm::vec3 colour;
};

Vertex points [] = {...};
```

When setting up the colour attribute, the following code works (with `m_location = glGetAttribLocation(...)`):

```
void Attribute::point_to_vec3 (GLsizei stride, const void * offset)
{
    glVertexAttribPointer (
        m_location,
        3,
        GL_FLOAT,
        GL_FALSE,
        stride,
        offset);
}

glEnableVertexAttribArray (m_location);
```

The naive version for a `mat4` doesn't work because apparently it has to be sent as 4 sets of 4 floats. I wrote this

```
void Attribute::point_to_mat4 (GLsizei size, const void * offset)
{
    auto o = static_cast <const std::uint8_t *> (offset);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        glVertexAttribPointer (
            m_location + i,
            4,
            GL_FLOAT,
            GL_FALSE,
            size,
            o + (4 * i * sizeof (GLfloat)));

        glEnableVertexAttribArray (m_location + i);

        glVertexAttribDivisor (m_location + i, 1);
    }
}
```

This is adapted from someone else's code, and having read the API documentation, I am still unsure if I'm doing this correctly. The matrix is behaving oddly in the shader.

Can someone please clarify what's going on with the multiple locations, and `glVertexAttribDivisor`?

Is the above code correct?

Comment: Is this a per-instance attribute? Otherwise, you don't need `glVertexAttribDivisor`. What are you passing as the `size`?

Comment: I haven't explicitly done anything with instancing. It's a bit over my head so you can probably assume "no", I guess. `size` is the stride of the whole vertex struct in C++.

Comment: Yes, if your entire vertex structure is in this buffer. Try to remove the `glVertexAttribDivisor` and see if it works.